# how to truncate on glob files through sudo?

Tags: bash, sudo

I need to truncate a big bunch of files with `sudo`. For only one this works:

```
sudo truncate -s 0 /var/lib/docker/containers/1cdd2386de3579-json.log
```

But with a glob like this `/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log` ...

```
$ LANG=C sudo truncate -s 0 /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log
truncate: cannot open '/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log' for writing:No such file or directory
```

Comment: You could also solve it without `truncate` as: `sudo bash -O nullglob -c 'for f in /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log; do > "$f"; done'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The globs are evaluated in the shell of the current user, before the elevated permissions of `sudo` are in effect (before the actual execution of `sudo`). The current user probably doesn't have permission to access the affected paths.

You can run it in a `sh` shell, that way the globs will be evaluated inside `sudo`'s shell:

```
sudo sh -c 'truncate -s 0 /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log'
```